# Loading images after htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Firstly apologies for the badly written headline. Couldn't explain the issue in a one liner.

I have a simple htaccess rule setup to have some fancy urls. I have also used this to combine and load all my css files using a controller.

The htaccess is as below

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(style\.css) Asset [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The index.php is a simple router routing to the correct controller and as you can see when style.css is called it transports the request to the Asset Controller. The problem i have is then how to load the images using the css files. The rewrite conditions are applied to the images as well which is something i want to avoid.

Has anybody come across a similar issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: do you mean that when browser requests image actually index.php is executed?

Comment: Yes. All image requests go to index.php?rt=$1. I dont want it to that

Comment: open browser's developer tools and check what URLs are actually called by browser, maybe images are not exists?

Comment: No mate. I think you have misunderstood me. The images do exists. A Standard Image Request to www.mysite.com/img.jpg goes to www.mysite.com/index.php?rt=img.jpg. Thats the problem

Comment: if you disable rewriteengine and try to open image - it will work?

Comment: oh, I've got it: you need to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` before second rewrite rule too

Comment: Tried it does not work. Still the request gets rewritten to Index

Comment: remove `[L]` from asset rule or move 2 conds and index above

Comment: That would mean my css would not load then.

Comment: if you add proper condition - it will load

Comment: Thats kind of the purpose i'm here looking for some help, because i am not sure what condition to add. Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: ok, I've posted one which should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change .htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

in controller check whether it is style.css in $_GET['rt']

if you want to change style.css to Asset on mod_rewrite level, use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} style\.css
RewriteRule .* index.php?rt=Asset&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

Options -Indexes # this line is optional
```

Comment: Hey, Getting close. Everything works fine apart from the css. So i can finally traverse the document structure by typing the image folder. Controllers are loading fine as well.

But, when the style.css is requested (http://localhost:8888/test/style.css)

It sends this request to index.php as style.css. In otherwords $1 is style.css but i want it to be Asset

Comment: remove `^` from the start of condition and rewrite rule

Comment: I got it to work by removing this line. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^style\.css


How can i pass some additional parameters on top of the Asset. i.e.: My url looks like this: style.css?p=library&t=css.. right now it just sends the request off to index.php?rt=Asset... how can i pass in the other parameters? Thank you so much for your help

Comment: do you mean style.css should go through index.php too? so only images should avoid rewriting?

Comment: Sorry, confused you again. Want style.css to go to Asset but with the other parameters as well ?p=library&t=css

Comment: Noo your previous answer was correct. Just need to send it to Asset with the other parameters ?p=library&t=css

Comment: Sorry but hit a problem, When i access http://localhost/img/ i can see the directory listing my images.. but when i do http://localhost/img/test.jpg it sends the request to index.php.. how can i stop this? this was my initial question

Comment: @SajunaFernando this is why I've asked - if you turnoff rewrite engine - can you get images loading?

Comment: Apologies mate, If i turn the rewrite engine off the images load fine but none i need those rewrites as well isnt it

Comment: I had to do this to get it to work. RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.jpg|\.png|\.gif)$ [NC]

Comment: @SajunaFernando I've got the problem, check updated variant, I've tested it locally - it works